# Query for finding if rows in a table,ordered,chronologically, satisfy a condition

Tags: postgresql

Let's say there is a table named **TableX**.

It has the following columns:

- **id**, sequence
- **col1**, varchar, think of this as an Enum, it can only have 5 values
- **col2**, integer, FK to another table, not null
- **col3**, text, this also will have a limited set of values.

I am trying to write a query that finds out whether **the first 5 rows** in TableX filtered by **col2** (*WHERE **col2**=1*, for example), and ordered by id in reverse order (*ORDER BY **id** DESC*), then grouped by **col3**, have a a certain value for **col1**

It isn't always the case that **TableX** will have 5 rows for all values of **col2**.

--

Here is a more concrete example:

I am searching for rows where col1=fail, in the actual table, fail will be represented by 2 values:

| id | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | fail | 1 | val1 |
| 2 | fail | 1 | val1 |
| 3 | fail | 1 | val1 |
| 4 | fail | 1 | val1 |
| 5 | fail | 1 | val1 |
| 6 | fail | 1 | val2 |
| 7 | success | 1 | val2 |
| 8 | success | 2 | val3 |

For col2=1 and col3=val1, the query shuould return col2, col3.

For col2=1 and col2=val2, there are only 2 rows, on top of that not all of them are "fail"; so, the query so return nothing.

For col2=2, there is only 1 row, on top of that it is not "fail" ; so, the query so return nothing.

Comment: Can you show us the query you have started on

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977). Ordering before grouping doesn't make much sense, by the way

Comment: What happens if there is a row `9, fail, 1, val1` where would you place it? Grouped with other `val1` rows? Or in order of `id desc`?

Comment: @RohitGupta I don't have one.

Comment: @mustaccio I agree that ordering before grouping does not make sense. 
I guess I implied that in saying that the rows have to be ordered by id desc than grouped by col3 …
The order of those 2 operations can be switched without much impact on logic or the desired outcome.

Comment: @Charlieface I gorup by col2, col3 then order by id DESC, then starting counting.

Comment: So something like this? https://dbfiddle.uk/OBPhXnju I don't get how the ordering comes in, what difference does it make which order you do it in?

Comment: @Charlieface The ordering is important because what I want to know is whether the first 5 rows (order by id descending) for groups of col3 and filterered by col2 have col1 as fail.

Comment: Then can we have a counter-example, a case where only the ordering makes a difference? I'm thinking you might want a row-number first, then the conditional aggregation https://dbfiddle.uk/w69dsoXI